# Accessing neon intrinsics with Beagleboard GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, neon

I'm using arm-linux-gnueabihf as my cross compiler under a VmBox Debian 8.1 on Windows 7 to compile for my Beagleboard. I've found much info on NEON/SIMD intrinsics but my compiler doesn't recognize the NEON intrinsics (i.e. uint8x8t).  I've seen refernces to arm_neon.h and neon.h but those are not in my tools. Is there a library I need to install?

My compiler command is arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
with options -O3 -pg -march=arm7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -ffast-math -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0

Comment: Example /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/include/`arm_neon.h` https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/gcc-arm-none-eabi/filelist .... Debian search https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=arm_neon.h

Comment: Thank you; I did since find this and added the correct include path for my tools. It now recognizes "neon.h" as an include but I now get a build error as follows: Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
gcc -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.2/include -O3 -pg -march=arm7-a  -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -mfloat-abi=softfp -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"eol_va_servo.d" -MT"eol_va_servo.d" -o "eol_va_servo.o" "../eol_va_servo.cpp"
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=neon’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=softfp’